# Formatting JSON from SQL Table Results in C# Other result

Tags: javascript, c#, json, serialization

Im trying to format JSON in c# in the following manner. Lets say I have the following table

```
Name  col2 col3 

Name1  1    2    

Name2  4    5    

Name3  7    8
```

I would like my JSON Output to be like so

> ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']

and

> ['1', '4', '7']
>
> ['2', '5', '8']

Now I have the following code:

```
public string Test()

     {

         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conect))
         {
             using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from  BASE.[dbo].[Orders_Date_to_Chart]() order by y desc", con))
             {
                 con.Open();
                 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                 da.Fill(dt);
                 System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new
     System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                 List<Dictionary<string, object rows = new 
    List<Dictionary<string, object();
                 Dictionary<string, object row;
                 foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                 {
                     row = new Dictionary<string, object();
                     foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                     {
                         row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                     }
                     rows.Add(row);
                 }
                 return serializer.Serialize(rows);

             }

         }
     }
```

Now I have result:

> [{"Name":"Name1","col2":1,"col3":"2"},
>   {"Name":"Name2","col2":4,"col3":"5"},
>   {"name":"Name3","col2":7,"col3":"8"}]

Comment: Excellent will be when result will be looks like:{
        name: 'col2',
        data: [1,4,7]
    }, {
        name: 'col2',
        data: [2,5,8]
    }

Comment: whats your question here?

Comment: I guess you need to convert an Array of Arrays to JSON, to make it happen :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string) to convert it to a custom object of your own choosing. An approach could be something likethis:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<ChildObject> ObjList { get; set; } 
}

    public class ChildObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int col2 { get; set; }
    public int col3 { get; set; }
}
```

And in your Test method do this:

```
    var rootObj = new RootObject();
rootObj.ObjList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(your string);
```

That would give you a list of objects and then you could do a loop an assign to new lists based on properties